# Are moon and sun setting in a water according to this hadith?

Tags: hadith, tafseer, hadith-interpretation, authenticity, science

Assalamualaikum,
I was reading tawilat al-quran for tafseer and i came across this hadith for surah anbya verse 33, which i couldn't understand. I am quoting directly, is this hadith authentic and how do we reconcile this with today's astrology?

The apparent meaning of the verse indicates that there is a sea or a river there and that the sun and the moon swim in it, they set and rise from there. Because Allah Almighty says that each one swims in an orbit. Everyone knows what swimming means. The root “Se-be-ha” (سَبَحَ) means swam in the sea or river. This is what is understood from the apparent meaning of the verse. There are also narrations that confirm this and have come down to us. According to what is reported from Ibn Abbas, The Prophet reported: “Allah has created a sea three leagues deep under the earth's sky. This spilling has been prevented and it remains in the air by God's command. And not even a drop drips from it. All seas are calm. But this sea flows at the speed of an arrow. Then its air condition is flat. It is like a mountain stretched between east and west, and the sun, moon and all the stars are floating in this sea. This is the meaning of the statement that each of them floats in an orbit.”